# Argument of type date is not assignable to parameter of type string

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I'm following a Angular and .net course.

I'm trying to set the photourl to a method.

I'm getting the following error\

> Argument of type date is not assignable to parameter of type string

The error is on the following line.

> this.changeMemberPhoto(this.currentUser.photoUrl);

The argument is the issue

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { JwtHelperService} from '@auth0/angular-jwt';
import { environment } from 'src/environments/environment';
import { User } from '../_models/user';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})

export class AuthService {
  baseUrl = environment.apiUrl + 'auth/';
  jwtHelpter = new JwtHelperService();
  decodedToken: any;
  currentUser: User;
  photoUrl = new BehaviorSubject<string>('../../assets/user.png');
  currentPhotoUrl = this.photoUrl.asObservable();

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}


  changeMemberPhoto(photoUrl: string) {
    this.photoUrl.next(photoUrl);
  }

  login(model: any) {
    return this.http.post(this.baseUrl + 'login', model).pipe(
      map((response: any) => {
        const user = response;
        if (user) {
          localStorage.setItem('token', user.token);
          localStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(user.user));
          this.decodedToken = this.jwtHelpter.decodeToken(user.token);
          this.currentUser = user.user;
          this.changeMemberPhoto(this.currentUser.photoUrl);
        }
      })
    );
  }

  register(model: any) {
    return this.http.post(this.baseUrl + 'register', model);
  }

  loggedIn() {
    const token = localStorage.getItem('token');
    return !this.jwtHelpter.isTokenExpired(token);
  }
}
```

The code is identical to the instructors, so I don't know what the issue is.

I've included the User class as requested

```
import { Photo } from './photo';

export interface User {
    id: number;
    username: string;
    knownAs: string;
    age: number;
    gender: string;
    created: Date;
    lastActive: Date;
    photoUrl: Date;
    city: string;
    country: string;
    interests?: string;
    introduction?: string;
    lookingFor?: string;
    photos?: Photo[];
}
```

Comment: I see the error. PhotoURL in the user class is a Date.

Answer (score 2):

photoUrl is a date in your class and is a string in your changeMemberPhoto method

In User class, change it  to :

```
photoUrl: string;
```

Comment: I agree with Cyril, Your User Class is setting photoUrl to date, but the other file is using it as a string. Maybe change photoUrl: Date, to photoUrl: String, in the User Class.

Comment: I am also agree with Cyril & Bobby. In Typescript types are important for method or property. In your User class you declare photoUrl as type Date. So if you want to use this property or pass it any method then it must be same type of method parameter. As your naming pattern photoUrl must be string. So please make your property photoUrl type string & your BehaviorSubject also accept string. So you can not emit other type it also show you error.